# Reorganize indexes with fill factor (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying following:

```
ALTER INDEX [spt_valuesclust] ON [dbo].[spt_values] REORGANIZE( FILLFACTOR=80 )
```

The above query is, unfortunately, not being executed. Can I use fill factor while re-organizing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I use fill factor while re-organizing?

Fillfactor only applies when

1. Index is first created
2. Or when Index is rebuilt, not during `reorganize`.

With above operation you are setting new fill factor and reorganize cannot be used to set new fill factor.

Reorganizing an index uses minimal system resources. It defragments the leaf level of clustered and nonclustered indexes on tables and views by physically reordering the leaf-level pages to match the logical, left to right, order of the leaf nodes. Reorganizing also compacts the index pages. Compaction is based on the existing fill factor value.

Index rebuild drops your current index and creates a new one. Reorganize does not drops any index it just removes fragmentation.

Please read [5 things about fill factor](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/04/five-things-about-fillfactor/)

Comment: Basically MS just forcing us to use Enterprise Edition